# What is the main constraint on running larger YARN jobs and how do I increase it?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager, hdp

What is the main constraint on running larger YARN jobs (Hadoop version HDP-3.1.0.0 (3.1.0.0-78)) and how do I increase it? **Basically, want to do more (all of which are pretty large) sqoop jobs concurrently**.

I am currently *assuming* that I need to increase the Resource Manager heap size (since that is what I see going up on the Ambari dashboard when I run YARN jobs). How to add more resources to RM heap / why does RM heap appear to be such a small fraction of total RAM available (to YARN?) across the cluster?

Looking in Ambari: YARN cluster memory is 55GB, but RM heap is only 900MB.
[image]
Could anyone with more experience tell me what is the difference and which is the limiting factor in running more YARN applications (and again, how do I increase it)? Anything else that I should be looking at? Any docs explaining this in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convenient way to tune your YARN and MapReduce memory is to use **yarn-utils** script.

### Download Companion Files ## [Ref](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_command-line-installation/content/download-companion-files.html)

```
wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/tools/2.6.0.3/hdp_manual_install_rpm_helper_files-2.6.0.3.8.tar.gz

tar zxvf hdp_manual_install_rpm_helper_files-2.6.0.3.8.tar.gz
```

---

### Executing YARN Utility Script ## [Ref](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_command-line-installation/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html)

You can execute **yarn-utils.py** python script by providing Available Cores, Available Memory, No. of Disks, HBase is installed or not.

[image: Example Image]

If you have a heterogeneous Hadoop Cluster then you have to create Configuration groups based on Nodes specification. If you need more info on that let me know I will update my answer according to that.